# EXC_BAD_ACCESS is generated in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview

Please consider this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Configure the cell.
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    NSDictionary *dict1 = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", dict1);
    if ([dict1 objectForKey:@"faqQues"] != [NSNull null]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [dict1 objectForKey:@"faqQues"];

    } 



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    faqQuesID = [[rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] integerValue];    
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //NSString *faqQuesID = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    NSLog(@"faqQuesID ######### %@",faqQuesID);

    [prefs setInteger:faqQuesID forKey:@"faqQuesID"];
    [prefs setInteger:faqTypeID forKey:@"passFaqType"];

    helpDetailsViewController *hdVController = [[helpDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"helpDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];     
    [self presentModalViewController:hdVController animated:YES];
    [hdVController release];
}


        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];    
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        return cell;   

    }
```

//  [prefs setInteger:10 forKey:@"faqQuesID"];  if i put manually integer then it does work but when i receive value form indexPath.row then it does show error
//  console error is

```
2011-12-05 18:16:30.312 test[3602:c203] -[__NSCFDictionary integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719e400
2011-12-05 18:16:30.314 test[3602:c203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719e400'
```

// i have waste a more couple of hours please give me suggestion how i can fix this problem?

Comment: "unrecognized selector" points you right at the problem.  Basically, your `rows` object isn't what you think it is.  (Did you properly retain it?)

Answer (score 2):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`rows` is an array of dictionaries. OK.

In your didSelectRow:

```
faqQuesID = [[rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] integerValue];
```

Which we can break down into:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
faQuesID = [dict integerValue];
```

NSDictionary does not have an `integerValue` method - which is exactly what the error message is telling you. Presumably you want to get the integer from a particular object in the dictionary.

```
faqQuesID = [[[rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"faqQuesID"]integerValue];
```

Assuming you have an `NSNumber` stored under the key `@"faqQuesID"`.

So, the your `didSelectRow` method should be something like:

```
NSDictionary *faq = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
[prefs setInteger:[[faq objectForKey:@"faqQuesID"] integerValue] forKey:@"faqQuesID"];
```

Comment: I think he could just get around this issue by using setObject rather than setInteger. It should work fine, just make sure to cast it into the correct object coming out.

Comment: @BillBrasky - he'd still need to use objectForKey unless he was storing the whole dictionary in preferences - which I guess is valid.

Comment: [prefs setInteger:2 forKey:@"faqQuesID"]; // i need like this types of conversion

Comment: @ashish : I have updated my answer with the code I think you should be using.

Comment: i have use it like bellow - but result is getting 0      NSDictionary *faq = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [prefs setInteger:[[faq objectForKey:@"faqQuesID"] integerValue] forKey:@"faqQuesID"]; 
    
    NSInteger ns = [prefs integerForKey:@"faqQuesID"];
    NSLog(@"******faqQuesID******* %d", ns); //******faqQuesID******* 0

Comment: Remember I made up that key, it might not be your real one. Can you log the FAQ dictionary as well?

Comment: @jrturton i have used your code                                      // but result get 0 for selecting  any row

Comment: OK, this is getting old :) **Where are you expecting this integer to come from**? In my answer I have _assumed_ it is part of the dictionary object held in your rows array that you are using to populate the table. Is that not the case? If not, what are you expecting the number to be? You haven't said this anywhere that I can see.